# How to save PendingIntent into sqlite database?

Tags: android

I am trying to block the notification by the subclass of NotificationListenerService. In method onNotificationPosted, I can get the contentIntent of blocked notification.

I want to call those contentIntent (PendingIntent) even if mobile has reboot.

How can I save PendingIntent into database, or another way could solve this requirement was welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to call those contentIntent (PendingIntent) even if mobile has reboot.

That is not possible, sorry. A `PendingIntent` is opaque to you and must be created by the other app. You have no way of forcing an app, after a reboot, to create some `PendingIntent` that you demand.

> How can I save PendingIntent into database

That is not possible either, for much the same reason.